# Groovy variable in SoapUI MockResponse Attribute

Tags: soap, groovy, mocking, response, soapui

I'm trying to get the current datetime in an attribute for a MockResponse in SoapUI.

What I've tried is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:localns">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <response instant="${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ').format(new Date())}"/>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've also tried it without the quotes around the variable, but it doesn't work.
I've seen plenty of examples for using variables as a text node, but not as an attribute, how do I do this?

EDIT The only way to get it to work was to declare a variable in the script below and pass that one to my attribute. This way, the quotes didn't get confused with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<response instant="${new Date().format( 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ' )}"/>
```

Comment: Well, the actual function doesn't seem to be the problem, but the way I inserted it into my response.

Comment: @Davio you mean the `=` at the start?

Comment: Perhaps, but with your way I just get an empty attribute.

Comment: Use `"` (double quotes) in beginning and end of the format as `"${new Date().format( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" )}"` @Davio

Comment: I got it to work by declaring the variable in my script `context.setProperty("now", new Date().format( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")))` and calling it with `attr="${now}"`